# Включение в recycler view фрагмента (item)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

Имеется отдельный фрагмент с Recycler View. Необходимо "включить (include)" в recycler view некоторые итемы, чтобы он их отображал. Как правильно это можно написать?
Ниже код fragment'a с RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.example.android.CenteredToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarNotes"
        android:background="@color/formRecyclerViewInMainRegistration" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ниже фрагмент `item`, который должен отображаться в фрагменте

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_notes_pick"
        android:elevation="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBtnPlay"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_button">

        </ImageView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: это нужно делать в apdater/ViewHolder

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример адаптера в котором можно произвести заполнение элементами, примеров вариаций в сети много.

```
class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

//this method is returning the view for each item in the list
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

//this method is binding the data on the list
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(userList[position])
}

//this method is giving the size of the list
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}

//the class is hodling the list view
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItems(user: User) {
        val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername) as TextView
        val textViewAddress  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress) as TextView
        textViewName.text = user.name
        textViewAddress.text = user.address
    }
}  }
```